# Change Tab header color in Windows Mobile 6.5

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, windows-mobile-6.5

I want to change the header of the tab control for Windows mobile 6.5.

[image]

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the backcolor of each tab page and that will also change the color of the tab (where TabPage1 and TabPage2 is drawn in your screen shot) too.

I do not know a way to solorize the tabs only.

Comment: Changing backcolor of individual tab pages doesn't have any effect on tab header.